# Why is System Preferences not recognising Pictures folder? [macOS 10.13.4]

Tags: macos, finder, photos, system-settings, wallpaper

I want to change my 2016 MacBook Pro's wallpaper to a custom image which is already in the Pictures folder.

If I launch `System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver > Desktop`, under `Folders` there is the `Pictures` one but it looks empty. 
Is it normal?

Only workaround by now is to click the '+' button and add the picture manually which, strangely, adds all of the pictures contained into the `Pictures` folder. 
NB: into my `Pictures` folder there are two custom created  subfolders which gets ignored by this last operation.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, this is normal.

This folder corresponds to the immediate (not including sub folders  folder located at `~/Pictures`.

You can access this folder by clicking Pictures in the Finder sidebar or by going to Finder>Go>Go to Folder> `~/Pictures`>Go

See pictures below

**Example 1**
[image]

[image]

**Example 2**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Indeed I had a ‘Wallpaper’ subfolder into the ‘Pictures’ one which immediately showed up after I added it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Also of note: In `System Preferences`, the "preview" image of the desktop is actually an "Image Well". You can drag and drop any image you want into that well and it will apply it to the desktop. You don't have to navigate through the list to get to the picture you want.